# Can I restore a deleted version file in AWS S3 using the new console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have the following scenario where I uploaded a file into s3

- test.txt - Uploaded at 10:15AM (latest version)
- test.txt - Uploaded at 10:00AM

I have 2 versions of test.txt and let's say I go ahead and delete my 10AM version so that i have the following

- test.txt - Uploaded at 10:15AM (latest version)

I assume that there's a delete marker that was created before latest version and I can remove it using the old console. Could I possibly do the same with the new console?

Comment: You can undelete only an object that was deleted as the latest (current) version. You can't undelete a previous version of an object that has been deleted. From docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/undelete-objects.html

Comment: Thanks hjpotter92!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two types of Delete available on an Amazon S3 bucket that has Versioning enabled.

- **Delete the object:** This adds a delete marker as the latest version.
- **Delete a specific version** (done by providing a Version ID with the delete request): That version is deleted. No Delete Marker is created. Cannot be reversed.

You can also delete a Delete Marker, which is simply treated as a different version, so it is deleted just like deleting a specific version.